# Is it possible to filter analytics to particular visits like you can filter to particular dates?

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to find out more information about particular visits in analytics?

For example, say I'm looking at new versus returning users. I then add a secondary column of "city". Ok, now I know all new users from yesterday came from new york, for example.

But what if I want to find out more information about those particular new vists from new york. Such as behaviors, technology, content. Is it possible to filter analytics to particular visits like you can filter to particular dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the technique is called **Advanced Segments**.  You can know more about it in the video bellow.

[How do I create and use advanced segments?](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=108040)

[Video: Advanced Segments in Google Analytics](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvkvMjPJXmM)